# How can i put my facebook's page in an iframe on any website?

Tags: html, iframe

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/MYUSERNAME/?ref=hl">   </iframe>
```

I've been trying this code: but it just don't work out , Kindly suggest me something here .

Comment: i am trying the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because of security issues;
Refused to display 'facebook.com/goforazhar/?ref=hl%22%3E'; in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Facebook denies it pages from being loaded into iFrame.
Refer "X-Frame-Options" documentation for more details;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Thanks for the reply , Please Suggest me , if there is any other way i can do this.

Comment: Please refer; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0.